# Error Occured While trying to restore minor version SharePoint 2013 Doc lib

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning

I was trying to restore the version of the document in doc lib to previous minor versions, but I encountered the following error:

[image]

Then i went to logs and searched for Correlation id and found the following:

```
> UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.
> 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore
> spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo&
> fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid
> databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[]
> metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq,
> SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq,
> SPDocumentBindResults& dbres) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
> bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
> String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
> bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
> pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
> pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
> pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
> pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
> UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
> pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
> Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
> pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
> UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
> pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
> pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
> bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
> String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
> bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
> pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
> pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
> pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
> pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
> UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
> pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
> Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
> pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
> UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
> pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
> pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
> bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
> String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte
> bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
> pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
> pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean&
> pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32&
> pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent,
> UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object&
> pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl,
> Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64&
> pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel,
> UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32&
> pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String&
> pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context,
> Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest,
> Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String&
> siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion,
> String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData,
> UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies,
> SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object&
> oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean&
> ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext
> context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean
> impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId,
> UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel,
> String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl,
> String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData,
> SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot,
> String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders,
> Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
> context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String
> virtualPath) 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath
> virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
> virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
> allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
> ensureIsUpToDate) 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
> context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
> allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
> throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
> context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
> allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
> ensureIsUpToDate) 
>     at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary
> contentTemplateCollection) 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
> error) 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
> context, AsyncCallback cb) 
>     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) 
>     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
> rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
> Int32 flags) 
>     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
> rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
> Int32 flags) 
>     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
> pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
>     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
> pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
>     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
> rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
> Int32 flags) 
> at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
> rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
> Int32 flags)
>





ZipUnitOfChangeAnalyzer: Failed with exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception of type 'Cobalt.ErrorException' was thrown. ---> Cobalt.ErrorException: Exception of type 'Cobalt.ErrorException' was thrown. 
    at Cobalt.DataElementGraph.GetDataElement(DataElementId dataElementId, Boolean nullIfNotFound, Boolean excludedDataOk) 
    at Cobalt.DataElementGraph.DataElementNode.EnsureDataElementFullyPopulated()

    at Cobalt.ObjectLoadStateInternal.TryGetDataForPartition(PartitionId partitionId, Atom& data) 
    at Cobalt.ObjectLoadStateInternal.GetDataForPartition(PartitionId partitionId) 
    at Cobalt.BinaryObjectNode.get_DataForRead() 
    at Cobalt.GenericFdaGraph.IntermediateNode.FindDataInternal(Range absoluteRangeToFind, UInt64 absoluteOffsetOfThis, Boolean regenerateNodeSignatures, LeafDataNode& leafDataNode, Range& leafNodeAbsoluteRange) 
    at Cobalt.GenericFdaGraph.IntermediateNode.FindDataInternal(Range absoluteRangeToFind, UInt64 absoluteOffsetOfThis, Boolean regenerateNodeSignatures, LeafDataNode& leafDataNode, Range& leafNodeAbsoluteRange) 
    at Cobalt.GenericFdaStream.OnReadFromBackingStore(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset) 
    at Cobalt.SmartSizingBytesBase.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset) 
    at Cobalt.OnDemandBytes.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset) 
    at Cobalt.Bytes.Read(Int64 sourcePosition, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
    at Cobalt.Bytes.ReadIfPossible(Int64 sourcePosition, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.LockBytesFromBytes.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CobaltStream.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead)     --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CobaltStream.ReadAt(Int64 offset, Byte* pv, UInt32 cb, UInt32& pcbRead) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.BytesFromLockBytes.Read(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset) 
    at Cobalt.StreamFromBytes.OnRead(Range rangeToRead, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset) 
    at Cobalt.StreamBase.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is typically for couple of reason.

- If for some reason the App Pool Account dont have the correct permission on the Content DB( DBO permission required).
- May be your Content DB is marked as Read-Only at SQL Server.
- also try to upload the file on the same library see if that succeeded.
- Also check if the quote of site not completed.

Lastly run this against your correlation ID `Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log" -Overwrite -correlation id ""`

Comment: Thank You for you reply Waqas, weird thing is its related to that document library. I created another document library in same site and uploaded the same file. I activated versioning and made several minor versions and 1 major versions. then i went to the individual file and tried to restore it into older minor version it worked.

Comment: what logs saying? looks like DL corrupted? do you have any customization on it?

Comment: logs are posted above, but i have no clue of what they re referring to exactly.

Comment: is that complete log for the correlation id? you can use merge-splogfile to pull the complte trace.

Comment: Log is huge, how do i post it here.

Comment: upload some where one drive or drop box and share the link here....But use the merg-splog to get related log entries

Comment: did you try different files int he same library if they are working or not? i am narrowing it if something wrong with file or whole librayr corrupt

Comment: i did use merge-splog but there are large chunks of logs. I will see if i can add it into dropbox.

Comment: Did you check this thing, that's what i blieve you have orphan which causing the issue...http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2014/03/23/detect-content-db-orphans-in-a-sharepoint-2010-farm-thru-windows-powershell-updated.aspx

Comment: That is little risky approach, i wont be allowed to do that in prod sites.

Comment: ok, but did you check if the problem is with library or just one item? another approach is move the site collection lower farm( using backup & restrore)

Comment: i think just that one item. i checked out and checked in document and created several minor verions, also a major version. Then i tried to restore it to an older minor version it worked. I beleive there is something wrong with that specific item.

Comment: how many versions you have for that item, is it really important to recover the minor version. i will download the files and upload it with new name and close the case...this thing taking more time then the worth.